# how to create a 10 *10 time table matrix using numpy broadcasting

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

Does anyone know how to create a 10 * 10 time table matrix using **numpy** broadcasting. I'm able to create a 10 * 10 time table matrix using `for` loop and **numpy** fromfunction, but I'm trying to achieve the same result using **numpy** broadcasting.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried (in code)?  You can probably do this by broadcasting two vectors containing `1` through `10` in a specific way.

Comment: I don't know `numpy`.  As a casual reader, I'm wondering what "numpy broadcasting" is, and why you want to use it.  Maybe explaining that would help to get you a better answer.

Comment: It's bizarre how so many of our users have ESP.  It isn't obvious to me that the OP doesn't know how to do what the linked question/answer describes.  In fact, they say outright that they do.  This question's title states clearly that the OP wants to explore **using numpy broadcasting**, and the word **broadcast** does not appear in the linked question/answer.  The use of that functionality should be addressed one way or another by the community before closing this question.

Comment: @Steve: The linked answer does use broadcasting.

Comment: @NicholasM - ah, ok.  Sorry to all the Closers if I was mistaken.  I just did a search for the word "broadcast" and did get a hit.  Maybe I screwed that up.  I've just noticed this pattern, and I don't get it wrong EVERY time ;o) - Looking again, I'll have to take your word for that.  I don't see anything in there that suggests broadcasting, but then again, I have no idea what we're really talking about anyway.   I was coming from the perspective of another user who might be as naive as me.  It's all good.  Thanks all!

Comment: @NicholasM - Thanks for you response, i was able to perform time table matrix, i followed below link to achieve my goal.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125652/create-a-20x20-matrix-using-numpy-broadcast